# Agora Cloud Recording is not working saving in s3 service

Tags: javascript, agora.io

I've been working hard to record web page in s3 service. So far, I was able to connect to Web Recording server and s3 without error. The response sent me a "resourceId" and "sid", but nothing has been saved in s3 service. When I call the "stop" method, I get the follow response:

```
{
"resourceId": "Etkl6g-zSB7EpP-Da1zN63dq8zdhhwI1ia8deuCa71S__FN07gcXYUdIiE6dO5pakQYNmVN184Sjyjs-nTWRe0oWJCb0kmOPOKZ4qlRxZS0OcnraSQqaxPeeHUMWK70mmJThYhsqcAF4YJtlxuePpdWVda5SlkaHBjOJIbvCx_z_QrLJ3sp3vVWmYfICxe942gMdAj_UhWoRFKkA8pv476CeR9dyIa4X2jH6C_zB1EZoSLH2iWR3z8Y12uGvpZ613HP7SoDGeQrgPHhRNDuRKKxtiQy7h4scSqoJWkvNLRxl8AXRU2vSPKO4k5SL3nn2u4WCf_BvCcu2PS4XGHsPcYFOjN_HTXeiwp7xeUsswO5zcn_7etfJoRzjn12nBL9s1OkAIuTt5kA_OqY8Rn-sFg",
"sid": "a8165c570e4f91e61d501b8271f01b54",
"code": 404,
"serverResponse": {
    "command": "StopCloudRecorder",
    "payload": {
        "message": "Failed to find worker."
    },
    "subscribeModeBitmask": 4,
    "vid": "284713"
}
```

}

I'm using Agora SDK 3.6.11 downloaded by NPM package. I don't know why is not working properly, any idea?